# Showing Graph/Chat and its table in PowerPoint

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

I have to show a graph related with table showing in PPT. But I am not able to show both table and its linked graph in  same ppt file. I make change in table values.. I have update its graphs also.
I want to show both table and graph in PPT. Is it possible?

Comment: which version of powerpoint are you using?

Comment: @Jonas i am using office 2013

Comment: Can you link to your current presentation?

Comment: @Jonas  Sorry I didnot get you.. I have slide in which i have to show both table and its linked chart side by side. as because the table data can change later.. I want to link them